# MySQL Error target table *view* of the UPDATE is not updatable

Tags: mysql, database-view

This is the query I am trying to run

```
UPDATE `jobseeker_view` SET `is_deleted` = 'Yes' WHERE `id`= '614'
```

On Local it works fine but on production database it doesn't work and throws this error:

```
#1288 - The target table jobseeker_view of the UPDATE is not updatable
```

I also checked permissions but no luck. Any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: Not all views are updateable. The rules around updates change between various mysql versions and perhaps even the sql mode setting influences the behaviour. Pls share the exact mysql version of both servers and the select statement of the view as well.

Comment: Live : 5.7.22, 
Local: 10.1.33-MariaDB I can see your point now. I will try this out will close this if this works.

Comment: @Shadow thank you for the edit.

Comment: So, your lical development database is not even mysql. Mariadb is **not** mysql, they have diverged long time ago. It is useful to have the same environment both in dev and prod. You can avoid situations like this.

Comment: @Shadow I just upgraded to MariaDB on production. It works now thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out databases were different on local and production.

```
Live: MySQL 5.7.22
Local: MariaDB 10.1.33
```

I changed the Live database to MariaDB 10.1.33 and it works now! Thank you @shadow for your help. Really appreciate it!